Clarification of "The meaning of a value is determined by the type of the expression used to access it"
From §6.2.5(1) of the standard:

The meaning of a value stored in an object or returned by a function is determined by the type of the expression used to access it. (An identifier declared to be an object is the simplest such expression; the type is specified in the declaration of the identifier.)

I am confused by the second sentence, specifically this bit: "An identifier declared to be an object is the simplest such expression" - how is this an example of what the first sentence is saying? What object is being accessed when we declare an identifier to be an object? Also, isn't this a declaration rather than an expression?
When I read the first sentence, I thought it was referring to a scenario such as the following:
int x = 3.2;        // `float` object is interpreted as an `int`

Here, the float object 3.2 is accessed by an assignment expression of type int and therefore the float object is interpreted as an int. Is this what the first sentence in the quote is saying?

Your example is that of a cast, where a float value is converted (via round-towards-zero) to a roughly-equivalent integer value. What the standard is saying is that the bit pattern of the data being accessed only has value because of the type of thing it is. A four-byte bit pattern can be a valid integer but an invalid float, for example. The character 'A' may have the same bit pattern as the integer 65, but they are different things.

@Dúthomhas Your example is that of a cast - yes, but it was the only example I could think of when trying to make sense of the first sentence.  the bit pattern of the data being accessed only has value because of the type of thing it is - this is how I thought of types ass well until I read the first sentence, which seems to say that the meaning of a value depends on the expression used to access it, not what it was declared as.

“The expression used to access it” has a type.

3.2 is a double not a float.

@Lundin Sorry, I am new to the language.


Is this what the first sentence in the quote is saying?

No.
Given float f = 1.f/3;, then printf("%g\n", f); interprets the bytes of f as if they are encoded with the scheme for the float type. The value printed will be the value determined using that scheme.
In contrast, printf("%hhu\n", * (unsigned char *) &f); interprets the first byte of f as if it is encoded using the scheme for unsigned char. Because the type used for access is unsigned char, the value of * (unsigned char *) &f will be the value determined using the scheme for unsigned char.

how is this an example of what the first sentence is saying? What object is being accessed when we declare an identifier to be an object?

When an expression is evaluated and there is an identifier for an object in the expression and the identifier is evaluated (e.g., is not the operand of sizeof), then the object identified by the identifier is accessed.

Also, isn't this a declaration rather than an expression?

It does not mean a declaration is an expression. It means that, after an identifier has been declared as an identifier for an object, that identifier in an expression is an expression for accessing the object.

Thanks @Eric. I think I had misunderstood the sentence "An identifier declared to be an object is the simplest such expression" as meaning that a declaration such as float f = 1.f/3; was the simplest such expression. But actually it is saying that an expression comprising of just the declared identifier alone (e.g. the expression statement f;) is the simplest such expression. Is this correct?

No. It's just f. No semicolon and the quote here is not related to statements. An identifier declared to be an object is just to exclude e.g. an identifier declared to be a class.

@user135792: Yes, that is what it is saying. Note that an expression may appear within another expression. So, for example, in x = f / (f+3), there is the subexpression x, the subexpression f / (f+3), the subsubexpression f, the subsubexpression f+3, the subsubsubexpression f, and the subsubsubexpression 3. So, where f appears in x = f / (f+3), it is an expression that refers to the object f, and that expression uses the declared type. In contrast, * (unsigned char *) &f also refers to (part of) the object f, but it uses a different type.

Thanks @WeijunZhou. My bad, I had added the semicolon to contrast it with the declaration, but that made my sentence incorrect since an expression statement is not an expression. An identifier declared to be an object is just to exclude e.g. an identifier declared to be a class - thanks, I was wondering about this.

@WeijunZhou" There are no classes in C. “An identifier can denote an object; a function; a tag or a member of a structure, union, or enumeration; a typedef name; a label name; a macro name; or a macro parameter” (C 2018 6.2.1 1).

@EricPostpischil Yes I may be thinking of C++ at the time of commenting. My comment is valid if you change "class" to "tag of structure".
